# Reference a variable from MySql database through PHP, to use in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've spent twelve hours trying to solve this problem, tutorial after JSON tutorial and no avail.

I have a MySQL online database with a table in it. This table has two columns, 'email address' and 'user rating'.

It seems very simple what I need to do, yet I am losing follicle after follicle of what precious little hair I have left. I'd like to reference the total amount of ratings(rows in the table) and the average rating from all users in my android application, so that I could set up some sort of text.setText(rating).

My php script references these well online, but for the love of me, I can't figure out how to reference them in Android.

```
$q = 'SELECT AVG(rating) FROM tbl';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$num_ratings = mysqli_num_rows($r);
echo '<br>'.$num_ratings;
```

I'm stumped as to how to go any further.

Comment: you're not using "email address" or "user rating". You're using an aggregate function on some OTHER field "rating". You then totally use mysql_num_rows wrong, and output HTML, not json. In other words, this code basically does NOTHING of what you want, except it might actually talk to the database, though we can't even assume that.

Comment: What's the objective here? To get the average rating of something?

Comment: The objective is to retrieve values within MySQl table and return the values to my app. These values are then stored in a variable and referenced later.

Yes, I want to display the average rating via a ratingbar and I want to display the amount of ratings.

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { $data[] = $row; }`